# How to Convert Numeric Value to String in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below makes a copy of the master sheet for each of the cells in the list (Named "Splitcode"), it then filters the first column in the data (Named "MasterData") and deletes any rows that don't have that cell in them. and loops until a sheet is created for every cell.

The code works perfectly on text values on column1 and on the list.
but  it won't work on numeric values (e.g account numbers).

I have been told I should be adding a CStr() Function, but I've never used it before so I don't know where to exactly add it.

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()    
  Dim Splitcode As Range    

Sheets("Master").Select    
Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")    
For Each Cell In Splitcode    
    Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)    
    ActiveSheet.Name = Cell.Value    

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Cell.Value).Range("MasterData")    
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & Cell.Value,Operator:=xlFilterValues    
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete    
    End With    

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData    
Next Cell    
End Sub
```

Comment: "Won't work" is not very helpful - can you tell us exactly what is the problem please and where it occurs?

Comment: You would be better off reading about how to avoid select and using a variable for your worksheet object. But e.g. `ActiveSheet.Name = Cstr(Cell.Value)`

Comment: yah that didn't work, I'm getting an error with this line

Comment: With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Cell.Value).Range("MasterData")

Comment: The problem is that if the value I'm using to separate the sheets is numeric it doesn't work.

Comment: `Sheets(cstr(Cell.Value))`

Comment: Would be useful to know where your "MasterData" range is located. My guess is that it is located in you "Master" sheet. So the problem could be that you're using the range that is not in the new sheet

The line that is calling the range:
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(Cell.Value)).Range("MasterData")

Comment: Thank you guys, this is working now

Comment: and MasterData was all the data on the master sheet

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: `CStr( expression )`

```
Dim LValue As String
LValue = CStr(8)
```

The LValue variable would now contain the string value of "8"

I see that you have `Cell.Value` in 3 places.  Also, check out this link.

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/number-text-filters.html

Finally, you may want to simplify things a bit.  If you have a header row in your range that you don't want to delete, add an offset to the range to exclude it:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```